# How a clause (order by) can be removed from a jOOQ query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is possible to remove a clause (the `order by` clause in my case) from a dynamically constructed query in jOOQ.

Suppose that after creating the query:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
SelectQuery<Record> query = create.select().from("myTable").where("fk = 1").orderBy(DSL.field("pk")).getQuery();
System.out.println(query.getSQL());
// select * from myTable where (fk = 1) order by pk asc
```

I want to change the `order by` clause or remove it to get only

```
select * from myTable where (fk = 1)
```

Is possible make this with jOOQ?. If is not possible and anyone knows a query builder library that allows this will be also welcome.

Comment: Instead of removing order by, can you not rework your logic so that you add it when you need it.

Comment: Of course i can, and it will led to a better design. I only want to know my options ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently cannot be done through the public API. In a future jOOQ 4.0, there *might* be a cleaner separation of [the DSL API and the Model API](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2198), where such a model API would allow you to freely manipulate all your query parts, including removing objects again from `SELECT` clauses.

Right now, you have at least two options to implement dynamic SQL:

1. Don't add the `ORDER BY` clause until you know whether you need it:

   ```
   SelectQuery<?> select = create
       .select()
       .from("myTable")
       .where("fk = 1")
       .getQuery();

   if (someCondition)
       select.addOrderBy(DSL.field("pk"));
   ```

   Alternative piece of logic:

   ```
   List<SortField<?>> orderBy = new ArrayList<>();

   if (someCondition)
       orderBy.add(DSL.field("pk").asc());

   create.select()
         .from("myTable")
         .where("fk = 1")
         .orderBy(orderBy);
   ```
2. Post-process / transform your query using an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) or a [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-sql-transformation/). This is more of a workaround in edge-cases, though.

In your particular case, you should probably go with option 1. [Another, more functional approach to tackling dynamic SQL generation is documented here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/).

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder. I will go with first because it will led to a better design in the code, i only want to know my options, because there is some technical debt in the project.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga: You mean technical debt with jOOQ code, or prior to introducing jOOQ? Note, I've added another code example to the first option. It's probably a better approach.

Comment: i don't explain myself correctly. I was not using jOOQ previously. Thanks @LukasEder

Comment: @FranciscoPuga: No worries, just checking :) We're keen on tracking down integration issues early on, which is why I asked.